Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension gives error on Collection Path when installing
I am working with the Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension.
When installing, it asks to add Collection Path.
My Collection Path is like below
Users/{userId}/Circles/{circleId}/Contacts/{contactId}/data
When I provide below Collection Path during the installation of Stream Firestore to BigQuery plugin it gives me data perfectly of Circles Collection.
Users/{wildcard}/Circles
But I want data in Contacts Collection.
What should be the Collection Path to get the data of Contacts Collection ?
I have tried to add below path to
Users/{wildcard}/Circles/{wildcard}/Contacts
but it gives me the following error when installing.

"ResourceErrorMessage":"Error creating trigger: The request was invalid: generic::invalid_argument: Document path is invalid. Provided: Users/{wildcard}/Circles/{wildcard}/Contacts/{documentId}"}

Notes:

wildcard is use for to get all docs inside collection.

userId is Firebase Auth Uid, circleId and contactId is auto id by firebase.



The problem comes from the fact that you use twice the same wildcard name (i.e. wildcard) in the following path:
Users/{wildcard}/Circles/{wildcard}/Contacts

Just use the first path in your question (which contains different wildcards for the document names) and it will work
Users/{userId}/Circles/{circleId}/Contacts/{contactId}/data

And if you want to export docs from the Contacts sub-collections, use the following path:
Users/{userId}/Circles/{circleId}/Contacts


Hey @arpitpatel, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

the problem with your solution is that I have Contacts collection in all userId and in all circleId.
for example
User1 -> User1's userid -> Circles1 -> Circle1's circled -> Contacts............
User1 -> User1's userid -> Circles2 -> Circle2's circled -> Contacts..........
User2 -> User2's userid -> Circles1 -> Circle1's circled -> Contacts............
User2 -> User1's userid -> Circles2 -> Circle2's circled -> Contacts

Hello @ARPITPATEL, what is your exact need? Your question does not indicate that you want to filter the documents to be send to BigQuery based on specific user or circle IDs

Users/{userId}/Circles/{circleId}/Contacts this is correct. it doesnt matter you have contacts in every user document anything within {} is a wildcard. You can to all the filtering in bigquery
